# Display the required error on the label of input type radio

Tags: google-chrome, input

I have replaced my radio inputs by some label pictures and set the display of the input to "none;"
Now when I'm trying to validate a form without checking the radio inputs, I can't see the chrome "required message" to display, because the input radio is not displayed, how can I make the message appear (only with required attribute)  on the labels instead of the input ? 
Thanks